# Linq GroupBy/Aggregation of Dictionary with Key that is a Tuple

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary whose Key is a four part Tuple of two objects (Object1 and Object2), a DateTime, and an Enum. The values stored in the Dictionary are objects of type Object3. Object3 objects contain an attribute which which is an integer value. Let's just say we can access it by method GetIntValue(). (This is 
a hypothetical example; let's not dwell on whether or not having a four part tuple as a key is a good idea!)

So the dictionary looks something like this:

`Dictionary<Tuple<Object1, Object2, DateTime, Enum1>, Object3> myDictionary`

The DateTime part of the key tuple is given in 15 min increments. I want to aggregate the keys up to the DAY level and sum the int values obtained from GetIntValue(). I know I can do this programmatically whether with loops, create other dictionaries/lists, etc. which may be better/faster, but I was wondering if this was possible to do in a single line LINQ statement?

Example data in the dictionary might look like:

```
Object1 | Object2   | Datetime          | Enum  | Object3.GetIntValue()
o1      | p1        | 09/07/2016 8:00AM | Type1 | 30
o1      | p1        | 09/07/2016 8:15AM | Type1 | 20
o1      | p1        | 09/07/2016 8:30AM | Type1 | 10
o2      | p2        | 09/07/2016 8:00AM | Type1 | 0
o2      | p2        | 09/07/2016 8:15AM | Type1 | 10
o2      | p2        | 09/07/2016 8:30AM | Type1 | 5
o1      | p1        | 09/08/2016 8:00AM | Type1 | 0
o1      | p1        | 09/08/2016 8:15AM | Type1 | 30
o1      | p1        | 09/08/2016 8:30AM | Type1 | 5
o2      | p2        | 09/08/2016 8:00AM | Type1 | 0
o2      | p2        | 09/08/2016 8:15AM | Type1 | 0
o2      | p2        | 09/08/2016 8:30AM | Type1 | 1
```

With the desired output being:

```
Object1 | Object2   | Date part of Datetime | Enum  | Sum of Object3.GetIntValue()
o1      | p1        | 09/07/2016 12:00AM    | Type1 | 60
o2      | p2        | 09/07/2016 12:00AM    | Type1 | 15
o1      | p1        | 09/08/2016 12:00AM    | Type1 | 35
o2      | p2        | 09/08/2016 12:00AM    | Type1 | 1
```

The output container may be a dictionary or other enumerable structure.

Comment: Why are you using a tuple for this you probably should create a class, and don't tell me it's because you don't want to override get hashcode, and equals.

Comment: (This is a hypothetical example; let's not dwell on whether or not having a four part tuple as a key is a good idea!)

Comment: Are the times sequential and you just want to do a group-by day or are the times random and you want to add up the sum to equal 24 hours

Comment: How would you create a `Object3` with a specific value.  Do you pass it to it's constructor or is there a property you can set.  If it's a method then the Linq code will be messy.

Comment: The times are not sequential. I just want to group by date adding all the int value attributes from the Value object

Comment: @juharr ``Object3 obj3 = new Object3();`` has an attribute which is an int. Say ``int a;`` It can be accessed by using method ``obj3.GetIntValue();``

Comment: @juharr yeah, I know it will be messy. It was a theoretical conversation that arose out of a code review at work. We were just curious if it can be done in Linq (regardless of how ugly).

Comment: @Tee, I meant how would you set it if you want the result to map to an `Object3`, but if you just want to map to the sum it's not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can pass the `int` value to the constructor of `Object3` it would look something like this.

```
var byDay = originalDictionary.GroupBy(
        kvp => Tuple.Create(
            kvp.Key.Item1, 
            kvp.Key.Item2, 
            kvp.Key.Item3.Date, 
            kvp.Key.Item4))
    .ToDictionary(
         grp => grp.Key, 
         grp => new Object3(grp.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value.GetIntValue())));
```

Or if you don't need it to map to `Object3`, but just an `int` you can change the last lambda to

```
grp => grp.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value.GetIntValue())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems to have worked. (I'm self taught on this  linq stuff, so it isn't always intuitive to me!)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the day and the values you can do this otherwise you can use @juharr's answer

```
 myDictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Datetime.Date)
             .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, 
                           v => v.Value.Sum(x => x.Object3.GetIntValue()));
```

This should group all your data by the date, then it will create a dictionary with the day to the summed up values